# triangle circumcircle geometry question

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be a triangle with sides AB = 20, BC = 17, AC = 12 , and denote w as the circumcircle of ABC . Let P be a point on the minor arc BC , and let K
be the foot of the altitude from P to BC such that BK = PK . What is the ratio between the areas of BP K to ABC ? Express your answer as a decimal to the nearest thousandth.

Can't figure out how to do it, the picture looks like below. Tried using Ptolemy theorem but couldn't solve the radial equations. The answer should be 0.049. Would appreciate any help.

- [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangle $PKB$ is isosceles and right-angled, so $\angle PBK=\angle PBC=45^\circ$. Hence $\angle PAC=45^\circ$.

We can calculate $\angle A$ by the cosine formula, getting approx $57.9^\circ$. Hence $\angle PAB=\angle A-\angle PAC=12.9^\circ$. Hence $\angle PCB=12.9^\circ$.

Let $BK=x$. Then $CK=12-x$, and $PK=x=(17-x)\tan12.9^\circ=3.89-0.229x$. So $x=3.168$. So finally $$\frac{\triangle BPK}{\triangle ABC}=\frac{x^2}{12\cdot20\ \sin A}=0.049$$

[image]